# My PC hangs and the screen flashes once a month

Tags: windows, windows-10

My PC hangs and the screen flashes on average once a month at random times. Sometimes it happens when I do something, sometimes when I do nothing.

I have to power off or reset to continue to work on my PC.

It looks very artistic, like fireworks. I attached two videos that show how it looks.

This has happened since I set up the computer.

Video 1: https://youtu.be/RZGnJx7RNSA

Video 2: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HpVZLpSNJqc

What could be wrong? How can I diagnose it? Has anyone had a similar problem?

I tried to do a stress test, but it didn't trigger the flashes.

Details:

- Windows 10 Home PL 64

My components:

- Intel Core i5-7500, 3.4GHz, 6MB, BOX (BX80677I57500)
- Gigabyte GA-B250M-DS3H, B250, DDR4, HDMI, DVI, VGA, mATX
- GoodRam PLAY DDR4 2x8GB, 2400MHz, CL15 (GYB2400D464L15/16GDC)
- WiFi - Asus PCE-N10
- Power Supply: Corsair CX450M 450W (CP-9020101-EU)
- Monitor Dell u2412m
- Drive SSD GoodRam Iridium Pro 240GB (SSDPR-IRIDPRO-240)

--- EDITED ----

I tested RAM by MemTest86+. Everything has been passed. I updated BIOS. And today, after 3 weeks, the same problem appeared. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Is your computer's memory properly seated? I've seen [several](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sHdHGJLGi7U) [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9SVoqNXcQNo) [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c86LZLQCMpk) showing what happens when memory is removed from a running computer, and your videos strongly resemble this. Also, you might want to run [MemTest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) to see if you have any memory issues.

---

Since you haven't specified a graphics card, see if installing one fixes the problem. It doesn't need to be expensive; even a cheap GeForce GT 1030 or Radeon RX 550 will do. If the problem persists, you probably have a faulty motherboard. If not, the processor graphics are the problem, though the added graphics card works around the problem (you don't need to replace the processor unless you need to use the processor graphics again).

Comment: I'm not sure , but then why would it happen once a month only. Moreover it is impossible to start a PC with a RAM card inserted wrongly.

Comment: Maybe it's a tiny bit loose? What happens if you gently tap on the computer case? If not... you'll probably need to replace the processor.

Comment: I'm not the OP ......

Comment: Can somebody *please* explain the downvote? I can't fix any perceived issues with this answer unless I know what exactly is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tested RAM by MemTest86+. Everything has been passed. I updated BIOS. And today, after 3 weeks, the same problem appeared. Any other ideas?

Comment: Updated answer. Try adding a graphics card and see what happens.

Answer (score -2):

Screen flickering in Windows 10 is usually caused by an incompatible app or display driver. To determine whether an app or driver is causing the problem, check to see if Task Manager flickers. Then, based on that information, you'll need to either update the app or the display driver.

Please see the official microsoft [page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/12374/windows-10-troubleshoot-screen-flickering) to fix this issue

**EDIT** :

Are you using iCloud? iCloud seems to have an issue where it will start flashing and flickering the screen.

Can you also disable "Windows Error Reporting Service" and "Problem Reports Service" from msconfig.

Comment: This does *not* look like a software problem. Notice that the screen goes black in one of the videos.

Comment: @bwDraco because of the display driver. Have you used Linux? It used to happen a lot when I used Linux. Never seen on Windows though

Comment: Oddly... I have never seen this under desktop Linux. This just looks like some sort of processor graphics problem but I can't be sure just yet. More often than not, on Windows, when the graphics driver fails, you get a brief flicker and a "Display driver stopped responding and has recovered" message, not a persistent flickering pattern on the display. This just does not look like a software issue.